# Release management in SVN

Tags: svn, release-management

When I look in the SVN log I really wish I could see markers that tell me when releases were done. I've seen this in other version control systems such as PVCS and [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/tag.html).

Can this be done in SVN? I've done a little bit of research and so far it looks like this sort of thing is not supported.

### Edit

We don't want to have to copy our source to a different folder for each release. This results in a huge amount of unnecessary duplication *of files on the developers machine*  and only gives us a record of the revision number of each release. I can do that using a text document!

### Edit2

My goal is to have a single view that shows me a chronology of my releases, between which I can see all of the code changes that took place between each release. This then makes it easier to compile release notes.

Comment: FWIW, the copies are cheap -- only references are copied, not files -- and they can be done entirely on the server, never cluttering your local workspace.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your objection, the copies happen on the SVN repository, not on the developer's machine.  Read the article I linked.

Comment: yeah. svn copy does NOT copy each file. It is done in constant time and usually takes about 1 second, regardless of how big the project is. try it. :)

Comment: ...and the developers machine should NOT have the "tags" directory checked out. ;)

Comment: So the thing I don't understand is how you can see the revision numbers of each release, on a machine that just has the "trunk" folder checked out.

Comment: Look at the repository on the server, not a specific working copy. For example, TortoiseSVN has a visual repository browser.

Comment: Something like this will help: svn info --depth immediates http://svn-url/project/tags/

Comment: crashmstr - obtaining revision numbers of releases using the Repo Browser is possible, but time-consuming (requiring right-clicks, waits on every release) and does not allow me to view a flat list of releases, with changes between each release.

Comment: I've written some tools to do this for my group, as well as generate XML log output of those changes that get saved along with the installer builds (and a log viewer app as well). I generally look at one release at a time, but custom tools could do what you want.

Comment: Developers machine shouldn't have the entire /branches/ folder checked out either. Just the branches the dev is working on and trunk.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Richard, tags are very close, but I wonder if what you need might not be a dedicated release branch.

For this, make a branch from trunk early on called something like 'Release'.
Then work on trunk as normal, when you're ready for a release, merge your changes from trunk into 'Release'. This is the only way that you should modify release.

You can then tag from release if you want, not 100% necessary.

But what this will give you is a branch that has a subset of the trunk's revisions in it. Find out your release dates with:

```
svn log --stop-on-copy svn://server/project/branches/release
```

This will give you a list of release dates (with the revisions). To see what's in each release do:

```
svn mergeinfo --show-revs=merged "svn://server/project/trunk" "svn://server/project/branches/release"@<release revision>
```

Also note that by working this way, you aren't limited to a strictly sequential release of everything in trunk - you can cherry pick revisions, excluding revisions if you don't want to release them just yet, but still including subsequent revisions.

Comment: Thanks Jim T - I think this might be just what I need!

Comment: Clear and concise and saving the day!

Comment: This is the solution we use as well. Our main stumbling block is where we have work committed to /trunk, that is not going to be released yet. This can cause tedious conflict resolution.

Answer (score 26):

Not as such.  The accepted way to do releases in SVN is to have a "tags" directory where your release source is copied for each particular release.  For example `/tags/release-0.11` ... There isn't anything preventing you from messing with the `tags` directory by accident, out of the box, but some people like to set up pre-commit hooks to prevent accidental commits to release tags.

Here's a [decent article](https://www.devroom.io/2006/11/21/svn-how-to-release-software-properly/) describing a release process in SVN.

Comment: And it's cheap to make tags because SVN doesn't copy any file contents unless they are changed.

Comment: Adam's linked article is the best mix of theory and real use case details I've found.

Comment: This link works, https://www.devroom.io/2006/11/21/svn-how-to-release-software-properly/

Comment: Note that "Release management" is more than just releasing the actual software with release notes or change log. The topic includes integration aspects, data privacy, quality, production environment, etc.

Answer (score 6):

> My goal is to have a single view that
>   shows me a chronology of my releases,
>   between which I can see all of the
>   code changes that took place between
>   each release.

Have you investigated the Tortoise SVN revision graph? If you tag each release (which as others have pointed out does not involve copying files, either on the server or the workstation), then you can see all the revisions in chronological order, with the tags indicating actual releases. You can diff between releases and/or trunk by hilighting the two revisions you are interested in and selecting diff from the context menu.

Answer (score 4):

Copying the trunk to a tags path in the svn repository is the way to achieve this.  It is an svn copy, so doesn't end up with duplicates of files on the svn repository server.   You only have duplicate files locally if you chose to checkout a svn path other than the trunk.  Commits on those working copies then go back to the svn path they were checked out from.

This is essentially a specific conventional implementation of branching in svn.  Take a look at the online svn book for more details.

Comment: Oh, and for the lazyweb users, the online svn book is at http://svnbook.red-bean.com

Comment: I don't believe that branching is going to help me here, for reasons clarified in my question edits

Answer (score 3):

The marker would be the commit message written when a tag for the release is made (a svn copy to the /tags). Atleast that is the most common method used.

Comment: Can you tell me more about this commit message jor?

Comment: This is what I did for a project.  The build machine would update a file and in the commit message it would insert the build number/version.

Answer (score 2):

While Subversion does not provide release management in and of itself, version control tools are not typically tasked with this activity.  What you are looking for is an activity/issue/change management tool that can interact with Subversion.

To that end we use Jira at my place of work and we link it with Subversion.  Jira provides a roadmap and change history that includes issues in each release.  Each one of those issues has links to the changes in source code control.  Thus you can link changes in source code with released versions.

I think it's generally better to keep these two tools separate.  Though Perforce in particular tries to tie the two together, they do so only simply.  There are some things, like emailing users of changes to issues, adding comments to issues, adding attachments to issues that are much better done in a specialized piece of software like Jira.  On the other hand Jira is not very good at versioning, merging and branching source ... which is better handled in a specialised piece of software like Subversion.

For full disclosure, there are other tools than Jira like Bugzilla, Trac, IBM Rational Jazz, etc. that can do the same thing with Subversion that Jira does though with varying levels of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the SVN Book's topics:

[Tags](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.tags.html)
and
[Browsing the Repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.history.html#svn.tour.history.browsing)

Tags and Branches are "copy on write", meaning that there are not extra copies in the repository. Generally an individual developer would not need to have a local copy unless he needed it for a reason (I.E. developing on a branch).

If you tag each release, then you can see the tags by browsing the repository. The above links talk directly about the command line tools, but there are also GUI tools like TortoiseSVN on Windows. You can get history, do comparisons, etc.

To see the changes made in a release, you would just show a log of the trunk from the revision of the tag you want back to the previous tag's revision +1. It sounds like extra work, but it is pretty simple once you get used to it.

With our build tools, we also commit back a file with some version number information back to the trunk, and the comment has the version number of the build. If your main code is in the trunk, this can also work as a marker for what is in a build (look between the version commits).

Answer (score 1):

+1 for using the commit message.

For a project I created an SVN user called build.  The build machine used this login for SVN.  Whenever the build machine/process did a build it also updated a file and the SVN commit message was the version/other identifier for the build.

Then we also created a tag for that build.  This way in the trunk we could see the builds when/where they are interspersed with other changes.

So my suggestion (simplest way to do it) is to create another files called build (or anything else you want) and append to that or just modify it in your build script/process and then check it back in/commit it with the name of the release version as the commit message.  Simple.  It will then show up in your history queries.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you know which revisions you are comparing you can do an SVN diff and you will see which files have changed and how between the two revisions.

Not sure about your total setup but someone mentionned TortoiseSVN.  That's definitively a good start.  I personally use Eclipse with the subclipse plug-in and it allows me to perform diffs in a graphical environment between revisions.  As long as you have your project your can compare any revision to any other revision and as such you don't need to have all kind of file duplication.

Also, we usually set up three directories in each repository.  Branches, Trunk and Tags.  As someone noted, Tags are used specifically for identifying a release.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem and the way I have tried to fix it for my company is to have a 'release' folder in trunk, this folder only contains the actual executable or what needs to be part of deployment.

I create a new folder for each release starting with '1.0.0.0' in 'release' folder and also tag the code with same release folder name i.e 1.0.0.0 in the case.

I am not sure if it is the right way to do it but it solves my problem to find out executable that I have deployed.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the normal svn convention of "tags/branches/trunk" at the root of your repository, developers typically would not want check out the entire repository, only from the trunk down.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer up a different approach that should help solve your stated problem: creating release notes and viewing code differences between releases.

We use a utility called SubWCRev that comes with Tortoise SVN.  We have a post-build event that grabs the SVN revision number and sticks it into a file - in the case of websites we put this in a file called version.html.  Then at any point in time you can tie your release (whether that's the releas currently in QA, Prod, or any other environment) to the exact revision number in SVN.  No more tagging, no more wondering what's included in a release, no more bugging developers to update a version file.

In order to determine what is has been included in a release, you can then just pull up the SVN logs from revision X to revision Y and copy the comments into a document and edit to make a pretty release notes doc.  The same is true for code review or diffing the releases; simply use the revision numbers tied to your version.html, properties.cs, readme.txt, etc.

I'd also suggest having some sort of artifact repository to hold your builds.  If you switch to using the SVN revision number as your version number, you can always go back to that exact revision in SVN which means you don't need tags or copies of your source for each release laying around in SVN.

Answer (score -2):

FYI,

SVN copy is not hard-copy, it's just linking therefore won't take any space other than changed files. And those versions will take space anyway. So creating a copy for every release will not take any space.

Comment: I know that the SVN copy is just linking. That's not the point - the point is that it doesn't really help me when I want to see the changes between revisions.